# Getting IncorrectResultSetColoumnCount exception in queryForList

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am using queryForList to get a list from DB ,

my code looks like,

```
List<RoleIdBean> role = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query , new Object[] {userId},RoleIdBean.class);

query = select * from role where userid=?
```

role table has two coloumns and roleIdBean has two variables .

When I am running this code it is saying `expected 1, actual 2`

Could someone please check where i am going wrong and assist how to use this method.

Comment: How should spring map the result to your class? It will only work for simple types like `String` or `Long`. You have to use a `RowMapper`.

Comment: @M.Deinum : thanks for your reply , as per the description of the method i thought it will map it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M. Deinum mentions, you have to provide implementation of [`RowMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) interface so that Spring knows which columns from your table to map to which properties of your object (`RoleIdBean`). For instance like this:

```
List<RoleIdBean> list = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM role_id", new Object[]{ userId }, new RowMapper<RoleIdBean>() {
    @Override
    public RoleIdBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        RoleIdBean bean = new RoleIdBean();
        // Set properties from the ResultSet, e.g:
        // bean.setRole(rs.getString(1));
        return bean;
    }
});
```

Comment: Bohuslav : Thanks for the reply , it worked for me .But it was not allowing @Override annotation . It worked when i removed it . Thanks!!

Comment: @mac Glad it worked. What Java version are you using? `@Override` Annotations on implemented methods should be supported for Java 6 and higher...

Comment: :):):) , i am using java 7 . Also, you used query method of jdbcTemplate , can't it be done with queryForList that i was trying?

Comment: @mac. `queryForList()` doesn't allow you to specify custom `RowMapper`. Also it calls `query()` internally (check source code) :) So the usage of `query()` here is correct. The problem with `@Override` can be caused by incorrect JDK compatibility level settings in your IDE. You can be using Java 7 but have lower compatibility level so that the IDE won't allow you to use the newer language features.

Comment: yes , i checked it is also calling query() internally .Thanks!